# How to use/convert sed to Python?

Tags: python, sed, code-conversion

Any idea to convert the given line below into Python?

```
sed 's+forwarding_link+'$link'+g' first.html > index2.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('first.html') as infile:
    data = infile.read()

data = data.replace('forwarding_link', link)

with open('index2.html', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(data)
```

This might useful

Answer (score 0):

Since `link` is a variable, it will stay as such in Python

You will have to read the file `first.html`, use `string.replace` to replace the matching strings, and then dump the result into `index2.html`.

```py
link = 'your link here'

with open('first.html') as infile:
    data = infile.read()

data = data.replace('forwarding_link', link)

with open('index2.html', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(data)
```